# JavaFX TableColumn with ObservableList as value

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, tablecolumn, observablelist

In my `TableView`, one of the `TableColumn` values is an `ObservableList`. To simplify things, it only contains `StringProperty` values. In my cell value factory for the column, I am concatenating the values together using the `Bindings` class.

The result I'm wanting should be a `StringExpression` that updates whenever the `ObservableList` changes.

The problem I'm having is that when any of the values of the list change, the generated `StringExpression` updates correctly, though when I add or remove values to the list, it will not update.

My first thought was to add a `ListChangeListener` to the row, but this seems impractical since there could be dozens or hundreds of rows to the table.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellDataFeatures;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class TestFx extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {        
        //Note, I never really see this "row" value directly, they're loaded 
        //in from a database, and there can be dozens or hundreds of 
        //rows for the table, so I don't if adding a listener to each one
        //is the best idea.
        final ObservableList<StringProperty> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        row.add(new SimpleStringProperty("test"));
        row.add(new SimpleStringProperty("one"));
        row.add(new SimpleStringProperty("two"));


        TableView<ObservableList<StringProperty>> table = new TableView();
        table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
        TableColumn<ObservableList<StringProperty>, String> concatColumns = new TableColumn<>("Concatentated Values");

        concatColumns.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList<StringProperty>, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList<StringProperty>, String> p) {
                ObservableList<StringProperty> row = p.getValue();

                List toConcat = new ArrayList();
                for (int i = 0; i < row.size(); i++) {
                    toConcat.add(row.get(i));
                    if (i+1 < row.size()) {
                        toConcat.add(", ");
                    }
                }
                return Bindings.concat(toConcat.toArray());
            }
        });        

        table.getColumns().add(concatColumns);
        table.getItems().add(row);


        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();        
        HBox buttons = new HBox();        

        Button add = new Button();
        add.setText("Add Item");
        add.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                row.add(new SimpleStringProperty("added"));
            }
        });
        Button remove = new Button();
        remove.setText("Remove Item");
        remove.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                if (row.size() > 0) {
                    row.remove(0);
                }
            }
        });
        Button change = new Button();
        change.setText("Change Item");
        change.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                if (row.size() > 0) {
                    row.get(0).set("Changed");
                }
            }
        });
        buttons.getChildren().addAll(add, remove, change);

        root.setCenter(table);
        root.setBottom(buttons);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);        
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I know "why" it isn't working. The `StringExpression` is linked to the `StringProperty` values of the list and not the list itself. Therefore, whenever I add/remove values, it doesn't update.

However, when I remove values (removing the first index), this causes the `StringExpression` to re-evaluate itself (I guess?), in which case the new added/removed values appear. (Press Remove and then Change)

Simply adding values won't do the trick. (Press Add then Change)

So how, in the cell value factory callback, do I work my code to listen to the `ObservableList` and return an `ObservableValue` that can concatenate the list and display when changes occur, including adding/removing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I figured it out, but I'd like input on whether or not my solution is practical.

I'm not familiar enough yet with JavaFX bindings and properties to know whether or not this solution is fine or if it would cause problems down the road.

```
concatColumns.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> p) {
            final ObservableList row = p.getValue();

            List<Observable> dependencies = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Object value : row) {
                if (value instanceof Observable) {
                    dependencies.add((Observable)value);
                }
            }
            dependencies.add(row);

            StringExpression se = Bindings.createStringBinding(new Callable<String>() {
                @Override
                public String call() throws Exception {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < row.size(); i++) {
                        //Check for Property objects and append the value
                        if (row.get(i) instanceof Property) {
                            sb.append(((Property)row.get(i)).getValue());
                        }
                        else {
                            sb.append(row.get(i));
                        }

                        if (i+1 < row.size()) {
                            sb.append(", ");
                        }
                    }
                    return sb.toString();
                }
            }, dependencies.toArray(new Observable[dependencies.size()]));
            return se;
        }
    });
```

The TL;DR version:

I created my own `StringExpression` using `Bindings.createStringBinding()` and I added the `ObservableList` as well as any of its values that were `Observable` objects as the dependencies to the `StringExpression`.

What I believe this will do is that whenever one of the list's values changes, the `StringExpression` is notified to update. Additional, when the list itself changes (add/remove), the `StringExpression` is notified to update.

Let me know if I'm wrong about the above statement!